# IntelliJ IDEA 14 - add "Execute gradle task" to toolbar

Tags: intellij-idea

In my IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 Ultimate, I want to add the "Execute Gradle Task" button (the one you find in the gradle sidebar with the gradle logo) to the "Navigation Bar Toolbar":

[image: Screenshot of the toolbar and where I expect the button to go]

I added the [gradle task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukp98.png) to the "Navigation Bar Toolbar", but the button does **not show up**, even after a IDE restart:

[image: Settings menu -> Menus and Toolbars -> View of gradle task being added]
Of course I hit the "Apply" and "OK" buttons.

[image: "Execute Gradle Task" not showing up]

What can I do to make the button show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reported issue ([IDEA-143545](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143545)) and it has been fixed in build 142.3833+.

The next major stable release containing this bugfix will probably be the release of IntelliJ IDEA 15 [in fall 2015](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+15+EAP), since the last early access build of IntelliJ IDEA 14 [is build number 141.2311](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14.1+EAP).